# Callback on percentage buffered using video.js

Tags: javascript, callback, video.js

How could I create a callback function on the event that a video (played with video.js) is (say) 50% buffered?

There's the myPlayer.bufferedPercent() method, that I've been using as in the code below that seems to work, but a callback would clearly be much better.

```
function checkBuffered() {
    if (videoPlayer.bufferedPercent()*100 > 50){
      clearTimeout(bufferedTimeout);
      $("bufferingText").hide();
      $("instructionsText").show();
      $('#feedback_keyPress').html(videoPlayer.bufferedPercent()*100);
    }
    bufferedTimeout = setTimeout(checkBuffered, 1000 / FPS);
  }
```

I borrowed a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/bababalcksheep/0a5u3ew4/) that might help

Answer (score 1):

According to the docs of video.js, the player already fires the `progress` event:

https://docs.videojs.com/player#event:progress

The `progress` event fires while the media is being downloaded. Therefor, it should be something like this:

```
videoPlayer.on('progress', checkBuffered);

function checkBuffered () {
  var buffPerc = videoPlayer.bufferedPercent();
  // rest of your code without setTimeout/setInterval
}
```